# MVC SelectListHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view-helpers

I use MVC and Razor. My model class has a BrandId and Brands property.I fill Brands from database and i use it with helper. But it can't validated when i submit form. Because BrandId is integer. But i can't set default value to 0 (zero) for this property. It's default value is space. What can i do? Thank you.

```
//my model
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Brands { get; set; }
}

//in my controller
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    var prodGroup = id > 0 ? _prodGroupService.Get(id) : new ProdGroup();

    return View(new ProdGroupViewModel
    {
        //How can i set default value to zero?
        Brands = new SelectList(_brandService.GetAll(), "BrandId", "BrandName"),
    });
}


//in my view
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label">Brand</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
    //How can i set default value to zero?
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BrandId, Model.Brands, "Choose", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, but if you want to validate that a value has been selected (not the "Choose" label) you can make the property a nullable int and add the `[Required]` attribute

Comment: Stephen, when i submit form my form not validated. Because brands 's dropdown 's default value is space. I want to it zero. If it 's zero so it will validate is okay.

Comment: What do you mean its a `space`? The value posted back will either be `null` or the value of the selected option. It can't be a `space` because that's not a valid value for `int`

Comment: i mean that my dropdown like this <option value="">Choose One</option> . but i want to like this <option value="0">Choose One</option>

Comment: Why would you do that? But I guess you would need to create a `SelectListItem` for each option and then insert an additional `SelectListItem` with Value=0 and Text="Choose" at the beginning of the list

Comment: because it's  <option value="">Choose One</option> so it's not validated when i submit form.

Comment: your `DropDownList` method will render the first option as `<option value>Choose One</option>` not `<option value="">Choose One</option>` and of course its not valid if you don't select an item (it does not match one of the option values)

Answer (score 0):

You can set default Value as:

```
public class Person {
    private const int DEFAULT_BrandId  = 18;
    private int _brandId = DEFAULT_BrandId ;
    [DefaultValue(DEFAULT_BrandId )]
    public int BrandId  {
        get { return _brandId; }
        set { _brandId = value; }
    }
}
```